# how do I add an azure role using a json within the azure cli?

Tags: json, azure, command-line-interface, rbac, azure-cli2

I am using the Azure CLI 2.0 and don't see any documentation on adding a custom role via a json document. Can someone help?

I assume it starts out like this: $  az role create .. but that doesn't exist, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

For **Azure CLI 2.0**, you can create a new custom role via JSON file containing the role definition using the Azure CLI command as below.

```
az role definition create --role-definition @ad-role.json
```

where **ad-role.json** is the JSON file which has the valid role definition residing in the same directory from where you run the command above.

You can refer to this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az_role_definition_create) for examples on how to use the latest Azure CLI to create the custom role.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom role in Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) if none of the built-in roles meet your specific access needs. Custom roles can be created using [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell), [Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli), and the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest).

To create a custom role using JSON, use the following cmdlet:

**azure role create --inputfile**

For more details, refer "[Create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli#create-a-custom-role)"

Manage user roles for access control with Azure Active Directory and service principals, refer "[az role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role?view=azure-cli-latest)".